# Heap corruption after creation of 2nd object

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, breakpoints

I am building the game Snake using OpenGL in VS. I have my class that handles the models, `VertexData`, and then the rest of the game in `Main`. Whenever I create the first object by calling `createModel()`, everything works fine. However whenever I call `createModel()` the second time, like to create the apple, there is about a 40% chance of Visual Studio triggering a breakpoint. everytime I call `createModel()` after that, like to create another body segment, the chances of it triggering a breakpoint increases. Is it due to where I am creating the object, or is there something else wrong? I saw that adding a copy constructor to the `VertexData` class would stop the crashing but it did not.

Main.cpp:

```
//includes
#include "convertToFloat.h"
#include "vertexData.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
#include <time.h>

//function prototypes
static void error_callback(int error, const char* description);
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void initWindow();
void destroy();
void changeLocation();
void update();
void render();
void loadModels();
void onStartUp();
void onCollect();
void createModel();
int roundUp(int numToRound, int multiple);
int roundDown(int numToRound, int multiple);

//object declerations
GLFWwindow* window;

//variables
int x = 200;
int y = 200;
int appleLoc[2] = { x,y };
int direction = 0;
int stepSize = 20;
bool start = false;
static double limitFPS = 1.0 / 15.0;
double lastTime = glfwGetTime(), timer = lastTime;
double deltaTime = 0, nowTime = 0;
int frames = 0, updates = 0;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<VertexData>> models;

int main(void)
{
    initWindow();
    loadModels();
    onStartUp();
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        nowTime = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime += (nowTime - lastTime) / limitFPS;
        lastTime = nowTime;
        while (deltaTime >= 1.0) {
            update();
            updates++;
            deltaTime--;
        }
        render();
        frames++;

        if (glfwGetTime() - timer > 1.0) {
            timer++;
            updates = 0, frames = 0;
        }
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    destroy();
}

void onCollect() {
    appleLoc[0] = roundUp(rand() % 620, 20);
    appleLoc[1] = roundUp(rand() % 460, 20);
    //models.at(1)->move(appleLoc[0], appleLoc[1]);
    //createModel();
}

void onStartUp() {
    srand(time(0));
    onCollect();
}

void createModel() {
    std::shared_ptr<VertexData> model{ new VertexData("models/snakeHead.md",640,480) };
    models.push_back(model);
}

void loadModels() {
    createModel();
    createModel();
}

void changeLocation() {
    switch (direction) {
        case(0):
            if(y<460)
                y += stepSize;
            break;
        case(1):
            if (x < 620)
                x += stepSize;
            break;
        case(2):
            if (y > 0)
                y -= stepSize;
            break;
        case(3):
            if (x > 0)
                x -= stepSize;
            break;
    }
    std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;
    std::cout << appleLoc[0] << " " << appleLoc[1] << std::endl;
}

void render() {
    for(int i=0; i<models.size();i++)
        models.at(i)->render();
}

void update() {
    if (start)
        changeLocation();
    models.at(0)->move(x, y);
    if (x == appleLoc[0] && y == appleLoc[1]) {
        onCollect();
    }
}

void initWindow() {
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Snek", NULL, NULL);

    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    gladLoadGL(glfwGetProcAddress); //important
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
}

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", description);
}

static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_W && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        direction = 0;
        start = true;
    }
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_S && action == GLFW_PRESS){
        direction = 2;
        start = true;
    }
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_A && action == GLFW_PRESS){
        direction = 3;
        start = true;
    }
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_D && action == GLFW_PRESS){
        direction = 1;
        start = true;
    }
}

int roundUp(int numToRound, int multiple)
{
    if (multiple == 0)
        return numToRound;

    int remainder = numToRound % multiple;
    if (remainder == 0)
        return numToRound;

    return numToRound + multiple - remainder;
}

int roundDown(int numToRound, int multiple)
{
    if (multiple == 0)
        return numToRound;

    int remainderInverseSorta = multiple-(numToRound % multiple);
    if (remainderInverseSorta == 0)
        return numToRound;

    return numToRound - multiple + remainderInverseSorta;
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void destroy() {
    for (int i = 0; i < models.size(); i++)
        models.at(i)->destroy();
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

vertexdata.h:

```
#ifndef vertextData
#define vertexData

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include "loadFile.h"
#include "convertToFloat.h"
#include "shaderLoader.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glad/gl.h> // include glad to get all the required OpenGL headers
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>


class VertexData {
    private:
        unsigned int VAO,VBO,EBO;
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;

        std::unique_ptr <Shader> shader{ new Shader("Shaders/3.3.shader.vs", "Shaders/3.3.shader.fs") }; //add shader path to constructor
        glm::mat4 trans = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    public:
        VertexData(const char* modelPath,int width,int height);
        VertexData(const VertexData& data);
        void render();
        void move(int x, int y);
        void rotate(int deg);
        void destroy();
};
#endif
```

vertexData.cpp:

```
#include "vertexData.h"

VertexData::VertexData(const char* modelPath, int width, int height) {
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
    std::unique_ptr<ConvertToFloat> conversion{ new ConvertToFloat(width, height) };
    std::unique_ptr<LoadFile> file{ new LoadFile() };
    std::stringstream modelStream;
    std::string substr;
    modelStream = file->load(modelPath);
    std::getline(modelStream, substr, ','); 
    int numVertices = stoi(substr);
    float* vertices = new float[numVertices*8];
    std::getline(modelStream, substr, '\n');
    int numIndices = stoi(substr);
    int* indices = new int[numIndices];
    int step = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices * 8; i++) {
        if(step!=7)
            std::getline(modelStream, substr, ',');
        else
            std::getline(modelStream, substr, '\n');
        vertices[i] = stof(substr);
        if (step == 7)
            step = 0;
        else
            step++;
    }
    step = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numIndices; i++) {
        if (step == 2) {
            std::getline(modelStream, substr, '\n');
            step = 0;
        }
        else {
            std::getline(modelStream, substr, ',');
            step++;
        }
        indices[i] = stoi(substr);
    }
    
    conversion->format(vertices, numVertices * 8 * sizeof(float));
    //binds id
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);


    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numVertices*8*sizeof(float), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // color attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, numIndices*4, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    //texture
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

VertexData::VertexData(const VertexData& data) {
    VAO = data.VAO;
    VBO = data.VBO;
    EBO = data.EBO;
    width = data.width;
    height = data.height;
    trans = data.trans;
}

void VertexData::render() {
    shader->use();
    unsigned int transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader->ID, "location");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(trans));


    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void VertexData::move(int x, int y) {
    float coor[2] = { float(x),float(y) };
    std::unique_ptr<ConvertToFloat> conversion{ new ConvertToFloat(width,height) };
    conversion->convertToGlobal(coor);
    glm::mat4 temp = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    temp = glm::translate(temp, glm::vec3(coor[0],coor[1], 0.0f));
    trans = temp;
}

void VertexData::rotate(int deg) {

}

void VertexData::destroy() {
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);
}
```

loadFile.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef loadFileH
#define loadFileH

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class LoadFile {
    private:
    public:
        LoadFile() {}
        std::stringstream load(const char* path) {
            std::ifstream file;
            std::stringstream stream;
            file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
            try {
                file.open(path);
                stream << file.rdbuf();
                // close file handlers
                file.close();
                return stream;
            }
            catch (std::ifstream::failure e)
            {
                std::cout << "ERROR::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
                return stream;
            }
        }
};
#endif
```

shaderLoader.h:

```
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glad/gl.h> // include glad to get all the required OpenGL headers
#include "loadFile.h"


#include <string>


class Shader
{
public:
    // the program ID
    unsigned int ID;

    // constructor reads and builds the shader
    Shader(const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath) {
        std::unique_ptr<LoadFile> fragFile{ new LoadFile() };
        std::unique_ptr<LoadFile> vertexFile{ new LoadFile() };
        std::string vertexCode;
        std::string fragmentCode;
        vertexCode = vertexFile->load(vertexPath).str();
        fragmentCode = fragFile->load(fragmentPath).str();
        const char* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
        const char* fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();

        // 2. compile shaders
        unsigned int vertex, fragment;
        int success;
        char infoLog[512];

        // vertex Shader
        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex);
        // print compile errors if any
        glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        };

        // similiar for Fragment Shader
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment);
        // print compile errors if any
        glGetShaderiv(fragment, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        };

        // shader Program
        ID = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(ID, vertex);
        glAttachShader(ID, fragment);
        glLinkProgram(ID);
        // print linking errors if any
        glGetProgramiv(ID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(ID, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }

        // delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessary
        glDeleteShader(vertex);
        glDeleteShader(fragment);
    }
    // use/activate the shader
    void use(){
        glUseProgram(ID);
    }
};
#endif
```

The areas that the breakpoint are triggered according to VS are: line 19 of loadFile.h `stream << file.rdbuf();`, line 27 of shaderLoader.h `const char* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();`, and line 75 of vertexData.cpp `}` which is just a closing bracket.
If I click continue after the breakpoint, I get the error `Unhandled exception at 0x7727FA1D (ntdll.dll) in snek.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x772BB960).`

EDIT:
convertToFloat.h:

```
#ifndef convertToFloat
#define convertToFloat

class ConvertToFloat {
    public:
        ConvertToFloat(int width, int height);
        ConvertToFloat();
        void convertToGlobal(float* input);
        void convertFromRGB(float* input, const int size);
        void format(float* input, const int size);
    private:
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
};
#endif
```

convertToFloat.cpp

```
#include "convertToFloat.h"

ConvertToFloat::ConvertToFloat(int width, int height) {
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
}

ConvertToFloat::ConvertToFloat() {

}

void ConvertToFloat::convertToGlobal(float* input) {
    input[0] = 2.0*input[0] / width;
    input[1] = 2.0*input[1] / height;
}

void ConvertToFloat::convertFromRGB(float* input, const int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        input[i] = input[i] / 255;
}

void ConvertToFloat::format(float* input, const int size) {
    int step = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (step < 3) {
            if (step == 1)
                input[i] = ((input[i] * 2) / height) - 1;
            else
                input[i] = ((input[i] * 2) / width) - 1;
        }
        else if (step < 6) {
            input[i] = input[i] / 255;
        }
        if (step == 7)
            step = 0;
        else
            step++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Inspect the values when the breakpoint is triggered to determine what the reason for triggering is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

Comment: ***there is about a 40% chance of Visual Studio triggering a breakpoint*** Your code has some type of undefined behavior.

Comment: Try removing functionality until you find the part that causes the problem

Comment: Can you show how the ConvertToFloat class is defined? I have a sneaking suspicion you're not supposed to be calling its `format` method with `numVertices * 8 * sizeof(float)`

Comment: Unrelated: Please stop doing `std::unique_ptr<Foo> bar(new Foo())`. You can just create a `Foo bar` with the same effect and less typing. Also, never use raw arrays if you can avoid it. `std::vector` is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `ConvertToFloat::format` takes a pointer and a length, here is your problem:

```
conversion->format(vertices, numVertices * 8 * sizeof(float));
```

`vertices` only has `numVertices * 8` elements and you are multiplying that by `sizeof(float)`. So that function will happily corrupt lots of memory after the `vertices` buffer.

The immediate fix is trivial: lose the `* sizeof(float)`, but I implore you to stop using raw memory and pointers and embrace `std::vector`.

If you declare `std::vector<float> vertices` you can simply pass that to `ConvertToFloat::format` and it will automatically a) know the size and b) alert if you do an out-of-bounds access.

You can always get a pointer to the backing array back by calling `vertices.data()`.

Also, if you define a

```
struct Vertex { float position[3]; float color[3]; float texcoord[2]; }
```

you can document your VBO format and *greatly* clear up your attribute assignment code:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size()*sizeof(float), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, color));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, texcoord));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size()*sizeof(int), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Ideally `vertices` would just be a `std::vector<Vertex>`, but I can imagine that does not immediately fit your loading code.